# Creation and Scheduled deletion of AWS Cloud Formation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to setup an environment on AWS by launching a stack via AWS Cloud Formation template. The stack would be created and then be scheduled for deletion automatically based on the TTL parameter in the template. There seems to be a problem only when the instance is getting launched, it errors out that *"Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration"*

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong in the template, it would be great.

Here is the link for the template in YAML: https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/rkbucket028/aws-openshit-cf-template_new.yml

I have already followed this article but there seems to be something wrong with it as well:-
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/scheduling-automatic-deletion-of-application-environments/#

Comment: Seems like the url is not accessible. Can you share the public url of the file? eg: looks like http://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.yml

Comment: Sorry about that Can you try the link now:-https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/rkbucket028/aws-openshit-cf-template_new.yml

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation rolls back if any of the resources have failed to be created (ie didnt responed in the predetermined duration). If you believe that it is only the process that is taking longer and not a genuine failure, you can either incorporate the wait condition, or better use resource creation policy time and count.

Source:
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html

PS: Your template url is not accessible. Check your bucket and file permissions on S3 bucket and share the public url

Comment: Sorry, Can you check the URL now. It is public.

Comment: Actually i think the instance goes not responding during creation, once the stack deletion script is getting injected inside it. Any idea how I can fix it? Maybe you can point out something that I am doing wrong from the cloudformation template